# CSS specificity and how to find classes

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I am struggling with defining specific CSS classes.
For example, I want to apply CSS to the Category page of Woocommerce only.
For example changing the background color of the category pages

**Current code:**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 690px){
    .container-wrap{
        background-color:#f6f6f6!important;
    }}
```

How can I make this specific for product pages only?
See for example this page: https://www.goedeshampoo.nl/product-categorie/conditioner/

Is this possible or does woocommerce now allow this via a css edit?

Comment: wordpress adds the product class on body inspect the page and paste the same selector after the body class

Comment: show the HTML of the element you want to change

Comment: Use `.tax-product_cat .container-wrap`

Comment: @ManojKumar How did you figure that out? I can see the code now you tell me, but how do you find this?

Comment: @dzinee WordPress adds the class for all product category pages. Taxonomy - tax, Category - cat. You can view the class added to the body after inspecting the code.